# clearstscache() not clearing file information PHP

Tags: php

I am writing a streamlined online file storage utility with php, and having an issue with the clearstatcache() when trying to list the files in a directory.

```
<?php
  $dir = dir("../archive");
  echo "<label for=\"Display Contents\" style=\"float:left;\">Contents of Archive
  </label><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div><br/>";

  //LIST FILES IN PARENT FOLDER
  while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false){
    echo "<li>Filename: <a href=\"../archive/" . $file . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . 
      $file . "</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <span style=\"float:right;\">
      File Type: " . filetype($file) . " &nbsp; 
      File Size:" . filesize($file) . "</span>
      <div style=\"clear:both;\"></div><hr/>
    <form action=\"remove.php\" method=\"post\">
      <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delete\" id=\"delete\" value=\"" .$file . "\">
      Delete this file <button type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">
      Delete</button></form> &nbsp; | &nbsp; 
    <form action=\"send.php\" method=\"post\">
      <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"send\" id=\"send\" value=\"" .$file . "\"> 
      Email this file <button type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">
      Send</button></form>";
    clearstatcache($file);
} $dir->close();
?>
```

The following displays my content correctly until the first file type change in the directory, which gives me an error:

"Warning: filetype() [function.filetype]: Lstat failed for 20130927-full.csv in C:\xampp\htdocs\archiver\includes\list.php on line 15

Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for 20130927-full.csv in C:\xampp\htdocs\archiver\includes\list.php on line 15"

Line 15 being to call to the filetype and filesize. I am not sure if I am using the clearstatcache improperly, if it should be called each iteration of the function, outside of the function, or if perhaps I need to consider a different method. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `clearstatcache` has nothing to do with these warnings. Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: I embedded the clearstat in the function to clear the cache at each iteration of the function. Still pretty green with php, but that is how I would construct in javascript so I assumed it would be similar in php. The function properly displays this info for the first two directory listings in the archive, but when switching to a csv or pdf it errors out. Oddly enough, .gif files in the directory display no errors, but also fail to display filetype and show filesize as 0.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what cache your would be clearing? What kind of cache would it be that affects the behavior of this code? It would be trivial to remove the call and see that it makes no difference either way. You are having trouble entirely because of filesystem-level issues, such as not enough permissions or some other malfunction.

Comment: Much thanks and appreciation.